# ¿Porque getMerchantParameters me devuelve nulo?

Tags: php, symfony

Estoy intentando integrar una pasarela tpv.php en redsys. Estoy utilizando php framework symfony.

El pago se realiza con éxito pero a la hora de confirmar si se ha realizado el pago o no, no consigo obtener dichos valores de vuelta, que sería la parte de notificación.

`$parameters = $redsys-getMerchantParameters($_POST["Ds_MerchantParameters"]);`

Mi pregunta es, como puedo acceder a estos parámetros. No encuentro el error y me estoy desesperando. Esta es la función que utilizo.

```php
 public function pagoPremium(Pedidos $pedido): Response {
     $fuc="555555555"; 
     $terminal="1"; 
     $moneda="978"; 
     $trans="0"; 
     $id=time(); 
     $amount="1,00";
 
     $urlOk = $this->generateUrl('registro_premium_ok', [], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
     $urlKo = $this->generateUrl('registro_premium_ko', [], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
 
     try{
         //Key de ejemplo
         $key = $this->getParameter("sha_key");
         $redsys = new Tpv();
         //$redsys->setAmount(($pedido->getImporte() / 100));
         $redsys->setAmount($amount);
         $redsys->setOrder($pedido->getNumeroPedido());
         $redsys->setMerchantcode($fuc); //Reemplazar por el código que proporciona el banco
         $redsys->setCurrency($moneda);
         $redsys->setTransactiontype($trans);
         $redsys->setTerminal($terminal);
         //$redsys->setMethod('C'); //Solo pago con tarjeta, no mostramos iupay
         $redsys->setNotification($urlOk); //Url de notificacion
         $redsys->setUrlOk($urlOk); //Url OK
         $redsys->setUrlKo($urlKo); //Url KO
         $redsys->setVersion('HMAC_SHA256_V1');
         $redsys->setTradeName('empresa');
         $redsys->setTitular('nombre');
         $redsys->setProductDescription('descripción');
         $redsys->setEnvironment('live'); //Entorno test
         $redsys->setAttributesSubmit('btn_submit', 'btn_id', 'Pagar', '');
 
         $signature = $redsys->generateMerchantSignature($key);
         $redsys->setMerchantSignature($signature);
         $hola = $redsys->generateMerchantSignature($key);
 
         $form = $redsys->createForm();
     } catch (Exception $e) {
         $this->addFlash('error', "Ha ocurrido un erro desconocido, vuelve a intentarlo mas tarde.") ;
     }
 
    
     return $this->render('premium/pagar_premium.html.twig', [
         'title' => 'Confirmar pago',
         'form' => $form,
         'redsys' => $redsys,
         'ok' => $urlOk,
         'ko' => $urlKo,
 
     ]); }
```

Aquí la otra función para recoger los datos si todo ok:

```php
 public function registroPremiumOk(Request $request): Response
     {
         try{
             $status = "failed";
             $redsys = new Tpv();
             $key = $this->getParameter("sha_key");
             $parameters = $redsys->getMerchantParameters($_POST["Ds_MerchantParameters"]);
             $DsResponse = $parameters["Ds_Response"];
             $DsResponse += 0;
             if ($redsys->check($key, $_POST) && $DsResponse <= 99) {
                 $order  = $redsys->getMerchantParameters($_POST["DS_MERCHANT_ORDER"]);
                 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                 $pedido = $em->getRepository(Pedidos::class)->findOneBy(["numeroPedido" =>
 $order]);
                 $pedido->setEstado(Pedidos::ESTADO_PAGADO);
                 $usuario = $pedido->getUsuario();
                 $usuario->setRoles(['ROLE_USER_PREMIUM']);
                 $em->persist($pedido);
                 $em->persist($usuario);
                 $em->flush();
                 $this->addFlash('success', "Pago completado correctamente, ¡Gracias por confiar en nosotros!");
                 $status = "success";
             } else {
                 $this->addFlash('error', "No se ha podido realizar el pago, vuelve a intentarlo mas tarde.") ;
                 $status = "failed";
                 //acciones a realizar si ha sido erroneo
             }
         } catch (Exception $e) {
             $this->addFlash('error', $e->getMessage()) ;
             $status = "failed";
         }
      return $this->render('premium/terminar-pago.html.twig', [
             'title' => 'Finalizar pago',
             'status' => $status,
             'parameters' => $_POST["Ds_MerchantParameters"]

         ]);
         }
```

Todo esta en el mismo controlador.php y este es el fallo que no puedo solucionar: Notice: Undefined index: Ds_MerchantParameters

Comment: Hola! Hazle debug a lo que recibes en el $_POST porque el mensaje te está diciendo que ese índice no trae datos. Usa `print_r($_POST)` u otra función que te permita ver qué viene en esa variable :)

Comment: Hola que tal. Gracias por tu ayuda.
Cuando realizo un `print_r($_POST)` o `print_r($_GET)` me devuelve un array vacío o null. Es decir que no se están enviando los datos del formulario o algo parecido. Estoy intentando ver donde está el fallo pero no encuentro la manera de hacer que funcione.